# Computer doesn't have a RJ45 network jack, can I use USB to connect to router?

Tags: windows-7, router

My computer is now right beside my wireless router, and on my computer I only have a wireless model, there isn't a port to connect directly into my wireless router!

My router does have a USB connection (that funny rounded square connection plug), can I just plug that into my computer?  (one end is a normal USB end, the other is a funny rounded square connection).

Comment: 'Rounded square' USB end? They're usually more "house" shaped :)   What make/model of router is this?  What happens when you actually plug the USB cord into the comptuer?

Answer (score 0):

In almost every situation, you cannot directly connect systems like that via USB. Best way to solve this problem is to purchase an inexpensive USB ethernet adapter, like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000062R4P). Just the first hit from google for usb ethernet adapter. If it's a good one, you shouldn't even need to install drivers, just plug and play. You can pick one up at Radio Shack or Best Buy too.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your router needs a USB connection to set it up your wireless PC should work with your wireless router.

The manual for your router will explain how to set it up.

If necessary you can buy a USB-Ethernet adapter that will allow you to connect the two using an Ethernet patch cable (AKA Cat-5 or Cat-6, RJ45).

For more detailed help, amend your question to include make and model of router and PC.

As for the connectors: your rounded square is probably a USB Type-B connector, used on peripherals.

**USB connectors**

[image: USB connectors]

*Image from [Wikimedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Types-usb_new.svg), author Bruno Duyé*